# How to modify the left side of a formula?

Tags: r

I want to modify the left side of the `mu.fo` formula with the value stored in the `response` variable. The idea is to obtain a new formula like this: `profit ~ x1 + x2` but actually I obtain `response ~ x1 + x2`.

How can I use the value stored in `response` variable automatically?

```
response <- 'profit'
mu.fo <- ~ x1 + x2
update.formula(mu.fo, response ~ .)
```

Comment: kind of roundabout `reformulate(attr(terms(mu.fo), 'term.labels'), response)`

Comment: Do you need the right hand side as a formula in an object or can we work around that if needed? Some of my answer missed that specific detail.

Comment: Yes, I need the right hand side as a formula to use it in model.matrix.

Comment: Don't you mean you need the resulting formula? You can always remove the response from a formula or pass the full formula to `model.matrix`: `model.matrix(y ~ x + z, data = data.frame(y = 1:10, x = 1:10, z = 1:0))` I really meant is the RHS variable or passed in as a formula by the user in your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response <- 'profit'
mo.fo <- ~ x1 + x2
mo.fo <- as.formula(paste(response, "~ x1+x2"))
mo.fo

profit ~ x1 + x2
```

Comment: Thanks @Hack-R, I used your response to permit a general  ``mu.fo`` using: ``mu.fo <- as.formula(paste(response, paste(as.character(mu.fo), collapse='')))``.

Comment: @fhernanb Awesome, glad you figured it out. If this was helpful, please feel free to upvote or mark as the solution. I'm addicted to rep points. ;) Give my regards to Universidad Nacional de Colombia!

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to achieve this.

One way is to use `as.name()` to encode the information `"profit"` as something other than a character string, as an R name (or symbol).

```
response <- as.name("profit")
frm <- as.formula(bquote(.(response) ~ .))
str(frm)

> str(frm)
Class 'formula'  language profit ~ .
  ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Here `response` is the symbol/name `profit`. We use `bquote` to substitute in the thing in `response` rather than a literal `response`, and coerce that expression to a formula. This way we end up with the same object as if we'd entered `profit ~ .`

```
> all.equal(frm, profit ~ .)
[1] TRUE
```

This works if `"profit"` is in a character vector too:

```
foo <- c("profit", "loss")
response <- as.name(foo[1])
as.formula(bquote(.(response) ~ .))
response <- as.name(foo[2])
as.formula(bquote(.(response) ~ .))

> foo <- c("profit", "loss")
> response <- as.name(foo[1])
> as.formula(bquote(.(response) ~ .))
profit ~ .
> response <- as.name(foo[2])
> as.formula(bquote(.(response) ~ .))
loss ~ .
```

The other way is to `paste()` strings together or use `reformulate()`

```
response <- "profit"
f1 <- formula(paste(response, "~ ."))
f2 <- reformulate(".", response = response)
str(f1)
str(f2)
all.equal(f1, f2)
all.equal(frm, f1)

> str(f1)
Class 'formula'  language profit ~ .
  ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
> str(f2)
Class 'formula'  language profit ~ .
  ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
> all.equal(f1, f2)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(frm, f1)
[1] TRUE
```

Which you end up choosing will really depend on what it is that you are *really* doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
update(mu.fo, as.formula(paste(response, "~.")))
# profit ~ x1 + x2
```

This differs from Hack-R's response in the sense that `mu.fo` is not hardcoded so if the RHS changes this will work as expected:

```
mu.fo <- ~ x + z
update(mu.fo, as.formula(paste(response, "~.")))
# profit ~ x + z
```